# Reading an Old Equation

Tags: soft-question

I have been self studying Whittaker and Watson when I came across this problem

[image: Kronecker Problem]

I am unsure what the first equation is supposed to be. Is it

$$\frac{e^{2 \pi i \nu x}}{1 - e^{2 \pi i x}} = \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=-n}^{n} \frac{e^{2k \nu\pi i}}{k - x}$$

or

$$\frac{e \cdot {2 \pi i \nu x}}{1 - e^{2 \pi i x}} = \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=-n}^{n} \frac{e^{2k \nu\pi i}}{k - x}$$

I would believe that the first equation makes more sense. Would this be a typographical error? Were such misprints common one hundred and twenty years ago?

Comment: It is almost certainly a typo.

Comment: @Sean Roberson Do you think it's $e^{2 \pi i \nu x}$?

Comment: Some numerical computations confirm it is $e^{2\pi i\nu x}$. Nice problem to prove it.